# find path of a key in a multi-dimensional tree-like array

Tags: php, recursion

hey, I have this array (the actual array can be several level deeps and spans a tree-structure)

```
array
  3 => 
    array
      4 => 
        array
          7 => null
          8 => null
      5 => null
  6 => null
```

Now, e.g. I want the path to key `7`, it can be shown like this:

```
array
  0 => int 7
  1 => int 4
  2 => int 3
```

**Can someone help me with such a recursion function?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will return you what you are looking for.  It will return null if the key is not found.

[In codepad.](http://codepad.org/ZLYJABkp)

```
function getkeypath($arr, $lookup)
{
    if (array_key_exists($lookup, $arr))
    {
        return array($lookup);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $subarr)
        {
            if (is_array($subarr))
            {
                $ret = getkeypath($subarr, $lookup);

                if ($ret)
                {
                    $ret[] = $key;
                    return $ret;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: End condition: if the key exists, it returns an array with that key;
Otherwise it checks each value in the array to see if it is an array.  If so, it runs itself on the subarray.  If the result is an array, it appends the current key on the return array and returns it.  If it can't find the lookup, it returns null (which fails the check on the return value).