# Moving single array to multi-dimension array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

My problem.. I have a PHP array that looks like this:

```
[1013] => [1154]
[1013] => [1322]
[1154] => [1525]
[1525] => [1526]
```

How can I take that and move it to something like this:

```
[1013] => [1154] => [1525] => [1526]
[1013] => [1322]
```

So it sort of makes a tree that associates to the top level array item.  I do not have control over how the data comes to me, it's generated through a third-party API and given to me just like that.

**Logic:** Client 1013 is the main account.  Client 1154 is a client of 1013.  Client 1322 is a client of 1013.  Client 1525 is a client of 1154.  I want to get it to a multi-dimension array so I can show this in a tree format.

Comment: On what logic should it be created?

Comment: You will have to iterate through the array and insert it into a new array.

Comment: I've been trying to iterate through it for the past few hours with no luck.  Literally gone through a ton of different methods.

Comment: @DainisAbols Think of this like. Client 1013 is the main account.  Client 1154 is a client of 1013.  Client 1322 is a client of 1013.  Client 1525 is a client of 1154.  I want to get it to a multi-dimension array so I can show this in a tree format.

Comment: I'm too lazy to test it out, but this ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381352/find-path-of-a-key-in-a-multi-dimensional-tree-like-array ) might get you started.

Comment: @DainisAbols this is.. somewhat, what I'm looking for but it would require me to know every relation in the array..

Comment: Well... you actually do know them. You go through the arrays with `foreach` and you will get the values anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go!:

```
<?php
// dataset
$clientset = array(
  array(1013, 1154),
  array(1013, 1322),
  array(1154, 1525),
  array(1525, 1526)
);

$children = array();

// make an array with children to see which nodes have none
foreach($clientset as $set) {
  if(!isset($children[$set[0]])) $children[$set[0]] = array($set[1]);
  else $children[$set[0]][] = $set[1];
}

// array with parents
$parents = array();
foreach($clientset as $set) {
  $parents[$set[1]] = $set[0];
}

// for each node with no children, begin the search!
foreach($clientset as $set) {
  if(!isset($children[$set[1]])) {
  echo getPath($set[1]).'</br>';
  }
}

// recursively search to parents and print them
function getPath($child) {
  global $parents;
  if($parents[$child]) {
    return (getPath($parents[$child]).' => '.$child);   
  } else return $child;
}
?>
```

This outputs:

```
1013 => 1322
1013 => 1154 => 1525 => 1526
```

The idea is to see which nodes have no children. Then, iterate through their parents. You probably don't need the output like it is right now, but I'm sure you can work it out this way. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk` php function to apply callback to each element of source array. Callback should create a new array according to your requirements. Callback function will take 2 parameters: value of current array element and it's key. Using that it's simple to build array you need.

Comment: I'm not too sure this will give me the proper results, do you have a sample chunk of code that would demonstrate a similar result?

Answer (score 0):

Chris, you should have just emailed me first. :-p

```
$test_array = array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
$output_string = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($test_array) -1; $i++)
{
    $output_string .= '{"'.$test_array[$i].'":';
}
$output_string .= $test_array[$i];
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($test_array)-1; $i++) { $output_string .= '}'; }
$new_array = json_decode($output_string, true);

var_dump($new_array);
```